# Magento2, Access item options through ObjectManager in minicart observer does not work

Tags: magento2, event-observer, mini-cart

I'm trying to get the value of `custom options` value in minicart observer. Using Objectmanager results to error "We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now."

```
<?php
/**
 *  CustomPrice Observer
 *
 * @category    CustomPricing
 * @package     CustomPricing_RentPricing
 *
 */
namespace CustomPricing\RentPricing\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $item=$observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $product=$observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
        if ($product->getData('rent_price')) {

                        $product_id = $product->getId();
                        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                        $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory‌​')->create()->load($product_id);
                        foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $options) {
                            $optionData = $options->getValues();
                            foreach ($optionData as $data) {
                                $optionPrice[] = $data->getPrice();
                                $optionDuration[] = $data->getTitle();
                            }
                        }


            } else {
        $price = $product->getPrice();
            }
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
}
```